# Arbitrary Substring Attribute Value Selector not working in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I have a Tag cloud that i need to style. Unfortunately it has no classes and I cannot edit the code.

The Problem:
I'm using the following code:

```
.tag-cloud a[style*="xx-large"]{
font-size:140% !important;
}
```

To target:

```
<div class="tag-cloud">
<a href="" style="font-size:xx-large;">Events</a>
</div>
```

the doctype is:`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

This is not working in Internet Explorer 7. As far as i know it is meant to work.

UPDATE:

The CMS i'm using is commenting out the doctype in ie7. This appears to be the issue. Not the CSS. Thanks.

Comment: "Arbitrary Substring Attribute Value Selector" fixed it, sorry

Comment: View source on your page, and see if it has a `<!DOCTYPE...` line.

Comment: Also failing in IE9 with IE7 Standards Mode

Comment: Does: 


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: Your test HTML file doesn't work because you need the doctype declaration before IE7 will make it work.

Comment: it works with a Doctype declaration.

Comment: what do you mean you cannot edit the tag?

Comment: Its in a CMS. I cannot change the code.

Comment: in ie9 the dev tools shows the doctype being commented out.
<!-- DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" -->

Comment: When you view the source its not commented out. WEIRD. This the issue thanks guys.

Comment: @etoxin: That IE behavior seems very familiar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not against using javascript, this could be solved really easily using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $(".tag-cloud a[style='font-size:xx-large']").css("font-size", "140%");
});
```

Comment: This is a solution. And probably what i'll end up doing.

Comment: Personally I'm not a fan of relying on Javascript to achieve CSS capabilities, but in this case, you'll probably see more cross-browser compatibility using Javascript than you would using the CSS Attribute Selector, so it's probably your best bet.